# Log specific events in global namespace to Console

Tags: javascript

I’m having a library which is exposing functions to the global namespace for other modules to call them.
Whenever one of this function is called I want to log this to the console including the parameters.

So in the Console:

```
window.globalLibrary
```

will return

```
{foo: ƒ, bar: ƒ,}
```

What I’m trying to achieve is to put an event listener whenever

```
window.globalLibrary.foo(‚testparam‘);
```

is called. I had a closer look on:

```
window.addEventlistener();
```

but it seems like none of these events is fitting my case.

Can anybody help out? Thank you!

Comment: Calling functions doesn't trigger any events.

Comment: is there a way to attach any in the global namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monkey-patch all the functions so they log to the console.

```js
window.globalLibrary = {
  func1: function() {
    console.log("Real func1");
    return "func1";
  },
  obj: "This isn't a function",
  func2: function(a, b) {
    console.log("Real func2");
    return a * a + b;
  }
};

Object.keys(window.globalLibrary).forEach(function(prop) {
  if (typeof window.globalLibrary[prop] == "function") {
    var func = window.globalLibrary[prop];
    window.globalLibrary[prop] = function() {
      console.log("Calling: " + prop + "(" + Array.from(arguments) + ")");
      return func.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  }
});

console.log(globalLibrary.func1());
console.log(globalLibrary.func2(10, 35));
console.log(globalLibrary.obj);
```

Comment: This seemed to work in the first place, and it logs the calls to the console just fine, BUT the actual functions are not called anymore, so the monkeypatch is a dead end at the end of the day. Calls are coming in but are not passed through, i tried to debug the func.apply(this, arguments); line in particular, but it looks just fine to me... any further ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I forgot to return the value from `apply`, so maybe that's the problem. I've fixed it, and added demo showing that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like custome events?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent